Handle NaN values in Scipy.mannwhitneyu (scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu)
I have a dataset of logIC50 values(say A) and another dataset of categorical clinical drug response (say B). There are mainly two important observations in B - sensitive and resistant. But there are many null (NaN) values in B. I want to use one-sided nonparametric Mann Whitney U test   to determine whether the estimated log(IC50) values of resistant tumors are significantly larger than sensitive tumors. But I do not know how to handle these NaN values.
I tried to use this code:
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

p_values = {}  # Dictionary to store p-values for each drug

# Assuming logIC50_df contains log IC50 values for different drugs
# Iterate through each column (drug) in logIC50_df
for drug in logIC50_df.columns:
    # Extract log IC50 values for the current drug
    resistant_log_ic50 = logIC50_df[drug][test_dr_new.iloc[:,0] == "Resistant"]
    sensitive_log_ic50 = logIC50_df[drug][test_dr_new.iloc[:,0] == "Sensitive"]
    
    # Perform Mann-Whitney U test (one-sided alternative hypothesis)
    statistic, p_value = mannwhitneyu(resistant_log_ic50, sensitive_log_ic50, alternative='greater')

    # Store p-value for the current drug
    p_values[drug] = p_value

    # Print individual p-value for each drug
    print(f"P-value for {drug}: {p_value}")

# Count the number of drugs with statistically significant discrimination
significance_level = 0.05
num_significant = sum(p < significance_level for p in p_values.values())

# Print the total number of drugs with statistically significant discrimination
print(f"Number of drugs with statistically significant discrimination: {num_significant}")

# Interpretation
if any(p < significance_level for p in p_values.values()):
    print("Reject the null hypothesis: estimated log(IC50) values are significantly higher in resistant tumors compared to sensitive tumors.")
else:
    print("Fail to reject the null hypothesis: there is no significant difference in estimated log(IC50) values between resistant and sensitive tumors.")

#But everytime, I use it, the results are bad. I doubt that NaN values in B dataset(i.e test_dr_new) is affecting my results. Please help in this regard.

please provide a small input set and expected output for the set. "But everytime, I use it, the results are bad." doesn't help anybody to help you out

How the test handles NaNs is controlled by the nan_policy argument.

The default is nan_policy='propagate', which causes the function to return NaN if there is a NaN in either sample.
nan_policy='raise' causes an error to be raised if there is a NaN in either sample.
nan_policy='omit' pretends as though the NaNs were not present at all. It behaves as if you had removed them before passing in the samples.

For example, to ignore the NaNs:
statistic, p_value = mannwhitneyu(resistant_log_ic50, sensitive_log_ic50, alternative='greater', nan_policy='omit')

See the documentation.

"in every iteration of the loop, resistant_log_ic50 is identical to sensitive_log_ic50 because you define the variables the same way. " why you say that ?  resistant_log_ic50 = logIC50_df[drug][test_dr_new.iloc[:,0] == "Resistant"]
sensitive_log_ic50 = logIC50_df[drug][test_dr_new.iloc[:,0] == "Sensitive"] seems different to me, what am I missing ?

Oops, I misread that. The rest of the response holds.
